# Receiving hard copy tier 2 CoS after UKVI panel sits on 11th

Tags: visas, uk

The UKVI panel sits on the 11th of every month to decide on the UK Tier 2 certificate of sponsorship visas. They say a decision will be made on this day and applicants will be notified within 5 working days. But does this mean I will receive the actual hard copy certificate in 5 working days?

Answer (score 0):

Before you are able to apply for a UK Tier 2 visa, the prospective employer requests a Certificate of Sponsorship (CoS) and then provides you with a certificate number which you use when submitting your visa application. You will not receive a physical certificate, although you can ask your employer for a print out of the details of the certificate.

> [**Certificate of sponsorship**](https://www.gov.uk/tier-2-general/eligibility) (added emphasis mine)
>
> A certificate of sponsorship holds your personal details and information about the job you’ve been offered. **It’s an electronic record, not a paper document.** Your sponsor will give you a certificate of sponsorship reference number to add to your application.
>
> You can only use your certificate of sponsorship reference number once. You must use it 3 months after getting it.

As you clarified in your comments, you are asking about the decisionmaking process for *restricted* Certificate of Sponsorship. The monthly allocation meeting is held on the 11th of each month (for an annual cap of 20,700 split into 12 monthly caps). The employer must supbmit its application by the 5th of the month and is advised of the decision by the 11th day of the month.

Comment: Thanks, so my prospective employer will get a certificate of sponsorship reference number within 5 working days? And then can just forward that onto me?

Comment: @wazzahenry No, it's the reverse: you can't apply for the visa until you have the CoS number from the employer. Only then can UKVI make a decision, after which applicants are notified within 5 working days.

Comment: I'm not asking about my visa. To be clear; will my prospective employer get a certificate reference number within 5 days of the 11th?

Comment: @wazzahenry you asked about *UK Tier 2 certificate of sponsorship visas* and what *you* would receive. You're conflating the process: the monthly allocation meeting for restricted COSs is on the 11th of each month (for an annual cap of 20,700 split into 12 monthly caps). The employer applies by the 5th of the month to be allocated a restricted CoS by the 11th of the month. The employer is advised of the decision by the 11th.

Comment: Ok. My prospective employer has already done the application, I'm just wondering when they will get the certificate reference number, so they can send it to me.

Comment: @wazzahenry You mean if they will...

Comment: No, I mean when they will get it.

Comment: @wazzahenry You’ll get the certificate reference number IF your prospective employer’s application is approved. They will know that by 11th of the month, as stated by Giorgio above.